# Xtabular: how can I convert to a single column?

Tags: tables

I am taking the example provided for a two column table in the following document, and modifying to suit my needs:

http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/xtab/xtab.pdf

I need to convert this to a single column table. Can anyone show me how to modify the latex code accordingly?

I am preparing a glossary of terms using a one column table....something like this

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| p{12cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Glossary of Variables}\\
S -- Source \\
D -- Destination \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The problem I am facing is that there are a lot of terms and the table runs into multiple pages. Hence I need to use xtabular package. Hope that clarifies my previous question.

Comment: Why do you need a table at all, a one-column table very rarely makes sense. In what way do you need the extra features of xtab over the standard latex tabular features?

Comment: It always helps if you show what you have done so far, to save everyone typing in a test document for you, make a complete small document and if it doesn't work the way you expect, post the entire document and ask about the error you have.

Comment: I shall edit my question

Comment: Aha.. You should be using `glossaries` package. Don't do like this.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)! You haven't done that even once in your 18 questions so far.

Comment: @HarishKumar I do not want a glossary but actually a table,......a glossary I presume would totally change the layout of my page.....I want a table...it has to be a table with just one column, but spanning multiple pages.....to be more precise, two pages....so you see the content is not large enough for a glossary, but does not fit within a page so that I could use a normal table

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg I presume the example I have provided is good enough for this question....based on the responses from others

Comment: @HarishKumar even though I used the term glossary, it is essentially the list and brief explanation of variables that I have used in a simulation.....hope that clarifies

Comment: Well, it isn't! Add `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}`, and the _relevant_ packages so that the code is compilable. Also, please don't sign your questions with "TIA

Vinod"; it's given automatically who asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist, here is again a two column table as it makes good alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xtab,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.

\begin{document}
%\topcaption{This is top caption}
%\bottomcaption{This is bottom caption}
%\tablecaption{this is table caption}
\tablefirsthead{
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Glossary of Variables} \\
\toprule
Variable&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}\\
 \midrule}
%
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries  Continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
Variable&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}\\ \midrule}
%
\tabletail{%
\midrule \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \midrule}
\tablelasttail{%
\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule}
\begin{xtabular}{>{\raggedleft$}p{1.5cm}<{$}>{-- \hangindent2em\hangafter1}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.5cm-3\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
    S & some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some
        text some text some text some text some text some text some text\\
    c & some text\\
    d & some text\\
    f & some text\\
    g & some text\\
    S & some text\\
    c & some text\\
    d & some text\\
    f & some text\\
    g & some text\\
    S & some text\\
    c & some text\\
    d & some text\\
    f & some text comes\\
    g & some text\\
    S & some text\\
    c & some text\\
    d & some text\\
    f & some text\\
    g & some text\\
    S & some text\\
    c & some text\\
    d & some text\\
    f & some text\\
    g & some text\\
    S & some text comes here too \\
    c & some text\\
    d & some text\\
    f & some text\\
    g & some text
\end{xtabular}%
\end{document}
```

Again, if you insist, here is a one column table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xtab,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.
\newcommand*{\variable}[1]{\makebox[2em][l]{$#1$ \hfill --}}
\begin{document}
%\topcaption{This is top caption}
%\bottomcaption{This is bottom caption}
%\tablecaption{this is table caption}
\tablefirsthead{
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Glossary of Variables} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}\\
 \midrule}
%
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{1}{c}%
{{\bfseries  Continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}\\ \midrule}
%
\tabletail{%
\midrule \multicolumn{1}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \midrule}
\tablelasttail{%
\\\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule}
\begin{xtabular}{@{}>{\hangindent3em\hangafter1}p{\linewidth\relax}@{}}
    \variable{S} some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some
        text some text some text some text some text some text some text\\
    \variable{c}  some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text comes\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D}   some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text comes here too \\
    \variable{D} some text\\
    \variable{c} some text\\
    \variable{D} some text
\end{xtabular}%
\end{document}
```